# Get AD user object GUID using Client Object Model in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, active-directory, jsom

I want to extract the `objectguid` corresponding to a username from the AD using javascript in Sharepoint.

Is it possible?

I can get some properties like the current username by using `SP.UserProfiles`, but I'm stuck at finding the objectguid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean `ADGuid` property, if so then the following example demonstrates how to retrieve this property:

```
function getUserProperties(loginName) {
   var deferred = $.Deferred(); 
   var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx);
   var properties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(loginName);
   ctx.load(properties);
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        deferred.resolve(properties);
    },
    function(sender,args){
        deferred.reject(sender, args);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Usage

```
getUserProperties(loginName).then(printUserProfileProperties,logError);


function printUserProfileProperties(properties) {
    var extProperies = properties.get_userProfileProperties();
    console.log(extProperies['ADGuid']);
}

function logError(sender,args) {
   console.log('An error occured: ' + args.get_message());
}
```